# SQL Server : merging two different conditions in the same where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    TRS.UMP AS CR_CODE_DVS, 
    TRSLIG.IdPai AS CR_IDPAI, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '06' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_THEO, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '07' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_REEL, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '08' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_ECART, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '04' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS ALIAS_CR_DEPOT, 
    ABS (SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '05' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END)) AS ALIAS_CR_RETRAIT, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '01' AND TRSLIG.Nature = '00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CR_NB_TRANSAC
FROM 
    TRSLIG 
INNER JOIN 
    TRS ON TRS.IdTrs = TRSLIG.IdTrs 
WHERE 
    TRS.DateRef = '25-10-2017' 
    AND TRSLIG.Nature = '00' 
    AND TRS.IdGrp IN ('06', '07', '01', '08', '04', '05') 
    AND TRS.IdTpv IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    TRS.UMP, TRSLIG.IdPai 
HAVING  
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '06' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '07' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '08' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '04' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0 
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '05' AD TRSLIG.MtUMP <> 0 THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0
```

The problem is I want to add a condition to verify that when I have `TRS.IdGrp = '07' or TRS.IdGrp = '08'` their corresponding `TRSLIG.MtUMP` must be `NOT NULL` to be dispalyed, but i have a condition in my where clause concering all the IdGrps so i didn't know how to restrict those two IdGrps to make my condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
   TRS.UMP AS CR_CODE_DVS, TRSLIG.IdPai AS CR_IDPAI, 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '06' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_THEO, 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '07' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_REEL, 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '08' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS CR_ECART, 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '04' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) AS ALIAS_CR_DEPOT, 
   Abs(SUM( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp= '05' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END)) AS ALIAS_CR_RETRAIT, 
   SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp ='01' AND TRSLIG.Nature ='00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CR_NB_TRANSAC
FROM TRSLIG INNER JOIN TRS 
  ON TRS.IdTrs = TRSLIG.IdTrs 
WHERE 
   TRS.DateRef = '25-10-2017' 
   AND TRSLIG.Nature = '00' 
   AND TRS.IdGrp IN ('06', '07', '01', '08', '04', '05') 
   AND TRS.IdTpv IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY TRS.UMP, TRSLIG.IdPai 
HAVING  (
       SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '06' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    or SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '07' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    or SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '08' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0  
    or SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '04' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END) <> 0 
    or SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '05' and TRSLIG.MtUMP<>0 THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END ) <> 0
        )
    AND 
     (
        SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '07' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END ) IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        SUM ( CASE WHEN TRS.IdGrp = '08' THEN TRSLIG.MtUMP ELSE 0 END ) IS NOT NULL
     (
```

Comment: at first  thank u for answering my question. ur solution did'nt solve my problem cause i didn't get the results that i want but nearly it can guides me to the appropriate solution to the expected result by adding my condition to INNER JOIN.

Comment: I guess I got it wrong. Dou you want to join tables whether or not it has NULL value on MtUMP column?

Comment: I want to join tables without rows where MtUMP is null where IdGrp ="07" AND IdGrp="08"

Comment: Then, I think my solution should work, what is the problem with it?

Comment: I executed the solution on sql server and it didn't give me the right result

Comment: They have to be null both of the them in the same row to be not dispalyed

Comment: You don't want to see any row that CR_REEL and CR_ECART columns are null at the same time. Is it what you want?

Comment: @ sarslan yes it is

Comment: same previous result

Comment: Are you see any CR_REEL and CR_ECART  NULL column? It is so weird.

Comment: actually, i don't understand the need, because we filter null at having. there shouldn't be null CR_REEL and CR_ECART same time.

Comment: Could you share your current and expected result?

Comment: **Current result:** 
i added 50 EUR so i have now THEO=50 REEL=0 ECART=0 
i add nothing then after re-entering ifound THEO=100 REEL=0 ECART=0
i close tpv so they will be  THEO=150 REEL=50 ECART=0
**Expected result:** 
i added 50 EUR so i have now THEO=50 REEL=0 ECART=0 
i add nothing then after re-entering ifound THEO=50 REEL=0 ECART=0
i close tpv so they will be  THEO=50 REEL=50 ECART=0

Comment: I expected to see NULL columns :)

Comment: Here there is no null columns cause it returns the SUM..so null columns will be added to aother values

Comment: But NULL value does not add any other values. I mean for aggregate sum NULL is ineffective.

Comment: ah i know but THEO, REEL and ECART are related so u can find REEL and ECART null and THEO not that'sw why it will be added and this is my problem. it doesn't have to be added in that case even if THEO IS NOT NULL